# Adding ImageFields to models

Tags: python, django

**I want to add ImageField to my model name of "models",**
But admin panel is failing....
I am beginner...My fail is very basic exception I know but I can't solve.

What should I do?
(sorry for my bad english,ı am high school student)

Model Code

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

#create a model and some models
class posting (models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=120,verbose_name='Başlık')
    content=models.TextField(verbose_name="İçerik")
    publishing_date=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Yayınlanma tarihi")
    photo=models.ImageField()

    #herposta title ına göre indexliyor

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Exception descr:

```
OperationalError at /admin/posting/posting/
no such column: posting_posting.photo
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/posting/posting/
Django Version: 1.10
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: posting_posting.photo
Exception Location: C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\blog\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 337
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\blog\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\blog',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\blog\\venv\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\blog\\venv\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\blog\\venv\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\blog\\venv\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\blog\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\blog\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sal, 14 Ağu 2018 02:01:09 +0300`enter code here`
```

Comment: did you migrated your model?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you still need to create a database migration `manage.py makemigrations` and then run it `manage.py migrate`.